# When I am trying to enter a node between doubly circular linked list it gives wrong output

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

Here I created a doubly circular linked list and try to add a node between the list but it is giving wrong output

I first created a doubly circular linked list and then displayed it and then I added a node between them and then again displayed it

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class node                                  //node class
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
    node(int a)
    {
        data=a;
        next=nullptr;
        prev=nullptr;
    }
};
class linkedlist                            //linkedlist class
{
    node *head,*tail;
public:
    linkedlist()
    {
        head=nullptr;
        tail=nullptr;
    }
    void addnode(int val)                   //creating node function
    {
        node *newnode;
        newnode=new node(val);
        if(head==0)
            head=tail=newnode;
        else
        {
            tail->next=newnode;
            head->prev=newnode;
            newnode->prev=tail;
            newnode->next=head;
            tail=newnode;
        }
    }
    void disp()                             //display function
    {
        node *temp=head;
        while(temp->next!=head)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<"   ";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
        cout<<"   "<<temp->data;
    }
    void addin(int val,int pos)             //addin function
    {
        node *newnode=new node(val);
        node *temp=head;
        for(int i=0;i<pos;i++)
            {
                temp=temp->next;
            }
        newnode->next=temp->next;
        newnode->prev=temp;
        temp->next->prev=newnode;
        temp->next=newnode;
    }
};
int main()
{
    linkedlist l1;
    int s,val,val1,pos;
    cin>>s;
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        cin>>val;
        l1.addnode(val);
    }
    l1.disp();                              //display function
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cin>>pos;
    cin>>val1;
    l1.addin(val,pos);                      //calling addin function
    l1.disp();
}
```

Input

```
3

1 2 3

1

0
```

Expected output

```
1  2  3

1 2 0 3
```

Current output

```
1  2  3   1
```

I don't know what mistake I am doing and also I am beginner so any tip is also too helpful for me

Comment: Most important tip, learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are printing the head node instead of the tail node due to the extra `temp=temp->next;` after the loop in the `disp()` function.
- You are adding `val` instead of `val1` after the loop in the `main()` function.

```
    void disp()                             //display function
    {
        node *temp=head;
        while(temp->next!=head)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<"   ";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        // remove this
        // temp=temp->next;
        cout<<"   "<<temp->data;
    }
```

```
    cin>>pos;
    cin>>val1;
    // add val1, not val
    //l1.addin(val,pos);                      //calling addin function
    l1.addin(val1,pos);                      //calling addin function
    l1.disp();
```

Answer (score 1):

in main function
you mistakenly add val instead of val1

```
cin>>val1;
l1.addin(val1,pos);
```

then in disp() function, remove temp=temp->next which is outside the loop.

```
void disp()                             //display function
    {
        node *temp=head;
        while(temp->next!=head)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<"  ";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        // temp=temp->next;
        cout<<"  "<<temp->data;
    }
```

and finally in addin() function, change pos to pos-1

```
for(int i=0;i<pos-1;i++)
            {
                temp=temp->next;
            }
```

that's all.

Comment: Your change of `addin()` function will make the output farther from the expected output. (`1   2      3(newline)(newline)1   0   2      3` will be printed and the position of `0` differs from the expected output)

Answer (score 1):

@MikeCAT was spot on, you are using val1 and passing val. However, I think the while loop in disp will skip the last element and not print it. and the logic in addin are not going to add the new element in the new place. Here is my version of your code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class node                                  //node class
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
    node(int a)
    {
        data=a;
        next=nullptr;
        prev=nullptr;
    }
};
class linkedlist                            //linkedlist class
{
    node *head,*tail;
public:
    linkedlist()
    {
        head=nullptr;
        tail=nullptr;
    }
    void addnode(int val)                   //creating node function
    {
        node *newnode;
        newnode = new node(val);
        if(head == NULL)
            head = tail = newnode;
        else
        {
            tail->next = newnode;
            head->prev=newnode;
            newnode->prev=tail;
            newnode->next=head;
            tail=newnode;
        }
    }
    void disp()                             //display function
    {
        node *temp = head;
        if (temp == NULL) 
        {
            cout << "List is empty " << endl;
            return;
        }
        do
        {
            cout << temp->data << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        } while (temp != head);

    }
    void addin(int val,int pos)             //addin function
    {
        node *newnode=new node(val);
        node *temp=head;
        for(int i=0;i<pos;i++)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        //newnode->next=temp->next;
        newnode->next=temp;
        newnode->prev=temp->prev;
        temp = temp->prev;
        temp->next = newnode;
    }
};
int main()
{
    linkedlist l1;
    int s,val,pos;
    cin>>s;
    cout << "val of size is " << s << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        cin>>val;
        l1.addnode(val);
    }
    l1.disp();                              //display function
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cin>>pos;
    cin>>val;
    l1.addin(val,pos);                      //calling addin function
    l1.disp();
}
```

Comment: note: order of numbers printed from this code for the input differs from the expected output in the original question.

Comment: Well, I agree and that is because the addin function has a flaw. when the position is 2 for example, it will insert the new node after the 3rd position. However, the author of the question can choose to keep the logic as he pleases. I merely present what is right. I mentioned that in my answer too @MikeCAT .

Comment: One more thing, without the disp change, the entire output will not be printed either. Hence, I would request the author of the question to look at my version of disp() which may be useful.